Python script not working through systemctl .service file
I'm trying to set up a simple script to run with systemctl timer.
To test if the .service file works i launch it: sudo systemctl start mioScript.service
but nothing happen. If i check the status:
mioScript.service - Myscript
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mioScript.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2024-04-13 14:38:57 CEST; 7s ago
TriggeredBy: ● mioScript.timer
    Process: 3804 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/user/main.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 3804 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 58ms

Apr 13 14:38:57 server systemd[1]: Started Mio.
Apr 13 14:38:57 server python3[3804]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Apr 13 14:38:57 server python3[3804]:   File "/home/user/main.py", line 1, in <module>
Apr 13 14:38:57 server python3[3804]:     from requests import Request, Session
Apr 13 14:38:57 server python3[3804]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
Apr 13 14:38:57 server systemd[1]: mioScript.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 13 14:38:57 server systemd[1]: mioScript.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

but if i open a terminal and i type: /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/main.py 
the script works fine.
I do not understand why launching the script throught the systemctl .service file do not find the requests module of Python (the module is already installed on the computer).
Am i launching properly the script? or should i launch it in another way?

Do you have any venv activated outside of systemctl?

I'm not sure exactly what you have written in your script file. But it looks like environment conflict so you can try out 2 general ways to fix it.

Set PYTHONPATH in environment variable.
In your .service file, try adding Environment="PYTHONPATH=path/to/modules".

Use virtual environment.
Try adding ExecStart=/path/to/your/venv/bin/python3 /home/user/main.py and install all your dependency in the environment beforehand.


